# Gradually ramping voltage on button press

Tags: voltage

I have a circuit with a button and a motor. How would I make the motor gradually ramp up speed over 1-3 seconds when the button is pressed and gradually slow down over 0.5-1 seconds when the button is released, instead of the motor going full speed immediately? The circuit may be either 12V or -12V depending on the desired turning direction.

This is a simplified version of an old electric desk control circuit. The desk moves too suddenly when the button is pressed and I need to slow it down.

As a programmer, my go-to solution for stuff like this is often a microcontroller, but I'd like to try using analog components if possible.

Even though I've had education in electronics back in the day, I don't know if there is a name for what I'm trying to do and how to search for more information about it. I'm stuck googling with too broad keywords. If the analog solution isn't too much more complex than a microcontroller one, please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Everything makes sense when you are ignorant of what needs doing to get there. It seems simple to just say, "Why can't a robot recognize a book laying on a table by itself in plain sight?" But then when you try and *do it* and are no longer nearly as ignorant about the process, you've also got your answer too. Because now you know why it is hard, now that you aren't so ignorant about it. Your question is like that. Seems simple on its face and I'm sure it makes a lot of sense to you. But... to those informed this is more of a tar-baby than you are imagining, I think.

Comment: Speak with the desk supplier.

Comment: Custom? one of these ? https://www.upliftdesk.com/

Comment: It's a generic and old desk. Works well enough but needs fine tuning. No need to replace it with another for something like this.

Comment: @jonk Seems a bit ignorant to assume I'm being ignorant for wanting to know more about a topic I presume to be relatively simple by my standards. I'm not an engineer but my education was a somewhat focused on electronics, in finnish and a long time ago. You seem to know how it is done, so instead of commenting on the nature of my question you could've provided the answer or even said that it's actually more complex than I'd think because x and y and z, in which case I'd have thanked you for your insight and started considering a microcontroller instead.

Comment: "The circuit may be either 12V or -12V" - does this mean the motor runs on 12V DC? Can you us show a schematic?

Comment: Motor runs on 12V DC. With 12V it turns clockwise and -12V it turns counter-clockwise.

Comment: @Pichan I'm using the term 'ignorant' advisedly and not as an insult or slur. I mean it as a technical term meaning "not well informed about a subject." Nothing more. We are all ignorant about a lot of things. Besides, I was speaking elliptically and not specifically. So your entire response is non-sequitur.

Comment: @jonk Fair enough, I apologise. Not saying you use too much fancy words, but for a non-native english speaker your text is somehow difficult to understand. Or very easy to misunderstand. Anyway, this is what I based my assumption about the relative simpleness of the circuit on. Not sure if it'd work as-is but at least it doesn't look too complicated: https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/xw65e2/voltage-ramp . Still, I'm beginning to think a microcontroller is the way to go.

Comment: @Pichan Understood. I speak some German and I know I do misinterpret a lot, myself. It is hard enough at times for a native speaker and listener to communicate well. I took it in that vein and assumed you'd misunderstood me. My point is that your problem could be quite difficult and not nearly so simple as "use MCU." In fact, I don't think there is a single panacea to this. I think it will take some research and thinking. That's mostly what I wanted to get across. That you need to be prepared for a learning process. Less so, a single bright line answer. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jonk I don't mind if there's a learning process involved. I could be in way over my head, but I consider the occasional reality check part of the learning experience. You're right, there most certainly isn't a single panacea (if at all) to this, though I can't see any real problems with Spehro Pefhany's answer, which is close to what I was originally contemplating. Being a programmer, an MCU-based solution is often the obvious one for me, but when your only tool is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail and so on :)

Comment: @Pichan Let's hope this is a case where if you have a hammer, you can then crack the problem walnut. But I actually think this is more like a case where you take out the hammer you have, but find that the problem requires chopping and planing wood, digging up gravel, pouring concrete, and ... well, yes, some pounding in of some nails. So your hammer will be helpful. But it's going to be very hard to use in planing and jointing the wood pieces, for example. Best wishes, regardless. Just keep at it until you solve it. I think that is the more important thing.

Comment: @jonk Thanks, will do. If I ever get to it and get it done, I'll be sure to post an update here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generically you may be able to do this by controlling a DC motor with PWM using and ramping the duty cycle from 0% to 100% over some time, and that will probably solve your problem.

The details are heavily dependent on the type and size (current/voltage) of motor- it may not be practical if the motor is of certain AC types for example.

I have retrofitted something that this and it worked well in the application (it happened to be gently lifting many millions of dollars worth of equipment rather than a desk top).

I used a cheap little microcontroller (PIC18F14K22) with a few lines of assembly code (less than 200 including comments and blank lines) to generate the timed 7.8kHz PWM signal to drive several large MOSFETs. A hardware overcurrent cutoff was included (probably why I picked that particular chip). I was able to leave all the original safety and other interlocks in place, just interrupting what was already present.

Comment: Thanks! I considered a microcontroller myself, but thought it could be simpler to do with analog components.

Comment: Pretty much anything these days is simpler with a mico. They are dirt cheap and if you can invest a few days in the learning curve pretty easy to use.

Comment: @RoyC I've some experience in microcontrollers and am a full time programmer. Not much learning curve there, luckily. I just thought that being a programmer, microcontrollers are very good hammers and every problem looks like a nail :D

Comment: Accepted this answer. If it's not too much trouble, could you tell me more? Anything special to pay attention to? I was considering an ATMega chip because I'm most experienced with that and Arduino, and they're easily available.

Comment: ATMega can certainly do it. MCU + 12-V capable gate driver (eg. MCP14A0602) + a biggish MOSFET, diode across motor. PWM at some kHz and ramp the duty cycle either with interrupts or delays if you use hardware PWM. If you want to drive the motor in both directions with software you would need a more complex circuit. Be sure to leave safety/limit switches in place. You can draw a schematic and ask another question here if you have concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Your desk circuit could indeed implement a slow attack and slow decay function for the key switch.

Adding one wouldn't be difficult in theory but may well be in practice as there's a warranty to invalidate, not to mention the violation of the current safety mechanisms that the manufacturer has guaranteed but won't afterwards.

But, answering your question, an electrical circuit to give the effect you want would be simple and straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! Not really worried about the warranty. It's an old desk and I don't think I'm risking more than just burning some electronics which is about as unsafe as having it unplugged :)